# Implementing sliding numbers into Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a little roguelike game with some enemies in there. When they hit me, I loose some health. I archieve this by calling this "well known standard" method.

```
    public void ChangeHealth(float healthToAdd) // Add or subtract health
{
    healthData.CurrentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(healthData.CurrentHealth + healthToAdd, 0, healthData.MaxHealth); // Change the current health
    healthView.UpdateHealthBar(healthData); // update the GUI
    if (healthData.CurrentHealth <= 0) // Kill the player at 0 health
        Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

So when I loose health, this happens instantly. Now I want it to increase/decrease smoothly step by step.

I found this code here for sliding numbers

```
float animationTime = 1; // The duration
float desiredNumber; // The calculated result
float initialNumber; 
float currentNumber; // The current value 

void AddToNumber(float value) // Change the Health
{
    initialNumber = currentNumber;
    desiredNumber += value;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (currentNumber != desiredNumber) // Create the sliding process
    {
        if (initialNumber < desiredNumber)
        {
            currentNumber += (animationTime * Time.deltaTime) * (desiredNumber - initialNumber);
            if (currentNumber >= desiredNumber)
            {
                currentNumber = desiredNumber;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentNumber -= (animationTime * Time.deltaTime) * (initialNumber - desiredNumber);
            if (currentNumber <= desiredNumber)
            {
                currentNumber = desiredNumber;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log(currentNumber); // Update the GUI ..
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I do not really know how to use it for my code or how to add it to my code. Is it possible to change my previous code this way, that it uses the sliding calculation?

It would be awesome if someone could help me out there.

Comment: `AddToNumber()` seems to be exactly what you want your `ChangeHealth()` method to do. Just add your additional logic like clamping and destroying and you should be able to call the new method instead of yours.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest using Coroutines. If you run your code in Update it will be calculated each frame. If you use Coroutines you may choose when they start and when they end. You can find some infos here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

```
IEnumerator HealthFade()
{
float time = 1f; // one second
float currentTime = 0f; // the time passed 
while(currentTime < time)
{
healthbar.fillamount = Mathf.Lerp(0f,100f,currentTime/time); // 0f = 0% hp 1f = 100% Hp, currentTime/time  give you a number between 0 and 1  = the amount of health you want to put inside the bar.
currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
yield return null;
}
}
```

Let me know if this is the behaviour you were looking for.

Comment: Hey, I just tried out your code, this is what i got: http://pastebin.com/ACXs3H1V  My method "ChangeHealth" is never called but i call it in the Update method. Is there something i missed?

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: http://pastebin.com/RJSnjjKS
Your method is now a Coroutine and it would be called with StartCoroutine() and the whole point of using Coroutines in your code is to use the fraction currentTime/duration so we get the health in the exact second we are in. The coroutines runs in paralel with the main Thread (Update function). If that's not the behaviour you were looking for, let me know please. Hope it helped you.

Comment: So I updated my code to this one here: http://pastebin.com/aMGnyHxu This is still working fine, but the "sliding" effect doesnt happen. It happens instantly. Is there a problem with `healthData.CurrentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(healthData.CurrentHealth + healthToAdd, 0, healthData.MaxHealth); // Change the data` ?

Comment: yeah, first of all 'currentTime = Mathf.Lerp(healthBeforeDamage, healthAfterDamage, currentTime / healthData.SlidingMaximumAnimationTime);' This is wrong. You don't need to change to currenTime at all. You only update it with 'currentTime += Time.deltaTime;'  The actual data you need to change is the one you need to update is healthData.CurrentHealth. And this would look like this : 'healthData.CurrentHealth = Mathf.Lerp(healthBeforeDamage, healthAfterDamage, currentTime / healthData.SlidingMaximumAnimationTime);'
I'm sorry I wrote it wrong in the link I have you

Comment: Huh, great, sorry for my mistake and please consider accepting the answer if it actually solved your problem fully. Have a great day :)